# LDAP ERROR - Cannot Login to Portal

Tags: java, liferay

A co-developer of mine has made some changes in Liferay's LDAP configuration and now we cannot log into our portal (LDAP or manual login) and the following exception is returned:

```
16:19:01,330 ERROR [http-nio-20110-exec-2][MainServlet:477] com.liferay.portal.ModelListenerException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
[LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'cn=admin,'
com.liferay.portal.ModelListenerException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: 
[LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'cn=admin,'

...
16:28:15,372 ERROR [liferay/scheduler_dispatch-4][PortalLDAPImporterImpl:210] Error importing LDAP users and groups
javax.naming.directory.InvalidSearchFilterException: Empty filter; remaining name 'dc=mycompany,dc=com'
```

I cannot access the Control Panel in order to reset the config - is there any way to reset this in portal-ext.properties or the database?

Answer (score 1):

In the portal-ext.properties you can use this key:

```
ldap.auth.required=
ldap.auth.enabled=

ldap.base.provider.url.0=
ldap.base.dn.0=
ldap.security.principal.0=
ldap.security.credentials.0=
ldap.auth.search.filter.0=
ldap.user.mappings.0=
```

Another solution is to add another ldap configuration. In order to do that just increment .0 on each properties like:

```
ldap.base.provider.url.1=
ldap.base.dn.1=
ldap.security.principal.1=
ldap.security.credentials.1=
ldap.auth.search.filter.1=
ldap.user.mappings.1=
```